# Logstash not sending data to elastic search when ran as a service

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

This is my config file stored at /etc/logstash/conf

```
input
{
file{
path => ["PATH_OF_FILE"]
}
}

output
{
elasticsearch
{
host => "172.29.86.35"
index => "new"
}
}
```

and this is my elasticsearch.yaml file content for network and http

```
\# Set the bind address specifically (IPv4 or IPv6):

\#network.bind_host: 172.29.86.35

\# Set the address other nodes will use to communicate with this node. If not
\# set, it is automatically derived. It must point to an actual IP address.
\#network.publish_host: 192.168.0.1

\# Set both 'bind_host' and 'publish_host':
network.host: 172.29.86.35

\# Set a custom port for the node to node communication (9300 by default):
\#transport.tcp.port: 9300

\# Enable compression for all communication between nodes (disabled by default):

\#transport.tcp.compress: true

\# Set a custom port to listen for HTTP traffic:
\#http.port: 9200
```

I am running elasticsearch and logstash as service.The problem is when I start log stash as a service it does not send any data to elasticsearch. However if I use the same config in the logstash conf file and run logstash from the CLI it works perfectly fine. Even the logs do not show any error.

The version I am running is 1.4.3 for ES and 1.4.2 for LS.
The system env is RHEL 7

Comment: You don't really have those backslashes in front of your '#', do you? This is probably a permissions issue, i.e. the user Logstash runs as doesn't have read access to the logs. Perhaps http://serverfault.com/questions/527706/logstash-cant-read-files-it-should-have-access-too will be helpful.

Comment: Hi Magnus, no there are no backslashes in real. Bdw I tried setting the permissions to 777, yet I face the same issue.

Comment: Do not make the files world writeable. Under no circumstances should logs have to be more than 775. What do the Logstash logs say if you enable verbose logs with the `--verbose` option?

Answer (score 0):

I also have encountered same issue...
When I exec command using -f option, it works normally, but when I start service, nothing happen and log file under /etc/log stash never updated.

What I did as the temporary counter measure is to exec the command below(with & option)

```
Logstash if conffile.conf &
```

With this, it work even if I logout from server.